# Ayuda con matriz en C#

Tags: c#, matrices

Estoy aprendiendo `C#` por mi cuenta y he intentando hacer una matriz a partir de otros `array` pero me dice lo siguiente:

> A nested Array initializer is expected

**Este es el código:**

```
string[] a = {"pequeña","mediana","grande"};
string[] b = {"esbelto","mediano","gordo"};
string[] c = {"cortas","medianas","largas"};
string[,] poolfen = {a,b,c};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir una array de dos dimensiones(matriz) y asignarle los array ya creados:

```
String[] a = new String[3] {"pequeña","mediana","grande"};
String[] b = new String[3] {"esbelto","mediano","gordo"};
String[] b = new String[3] {"cortas","medianas","largas"};

String[][] matriz = new String[][] {  a ,  b ,  c };

Console.Write(matriz[1][2]);
```

Salida:

```
gordo
```

Comment: Muchas gracis, ya me funciono